# How to Parse Image URL and Save It On Cloudinary With Django?

Tags: python, django, cloudinary

I'm having some issues integrating **Cloudinary** into **Django**.

I have a form on my site, that excepts URLs. This URL is then being parsed with BS4 to find an image URL:

```
def add(request):
    ...
    product.image_url = soup.find('meta', property='image')["content"]
    ...
```

I then pass URL to **cloudinary.uploader**:

```
    ...
    product.image = cloudinary.uploader.upload(product.image_url)
    product.save()
    return redirect(product.get_absolute_url())
```

I've added the **CloudinaryField** to the product's class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = CloudinaryField('image')
```

When I'm trying to add the product, I'm getting the following error: `ProgrammingError at /product/add` `can't adapt type 'dict'` Would appreciate your help with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding this:

```
product.image = cloudinary.uploader.upload(product.image_url)['public_id']
```